# Problem on compact spaces with exhaustive function

Tags: general-topology

Let f be a continuous and exhaustive function from $X$ to $Y$, two topological spaces. Assume that $Y$ is compact and that for all $y \in Y$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact. Prove that X is compact.

Comment: What do you mean by "exhaustive"?

Comment: @DavidHartley Online I found it meaning surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is just continuous and onto ($f[X] = Y$) and $Y$ compact with compact fibres, this is false.

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology, $Y = \mathbb{R}$ in the co-finite topology, and $f(x) = x$. This is continuous, all $f^{-1}[\{x\}]= \{x\}$ are compact and $Y$ is compact, but $X$ is not compact.

Comment: There are no extra hypothesis in the statement of the problem, so it must be an author's error. Thanks anyway

Comment: @PolMestresRamon Not working in metric spaces, e.g.?